# android how to rotate canvas rect

Tags: android, canvas, path, rotation, rect

i create a rectangle in a specific size, and now i want rotate it to 45 degree, i used canvas.rotate, matrix, but not working. how is the proper way to rotate canvas in android? and i'm curios about Path.Direction.CW, is it used for rotation? but i don't see any rotation function in Path()

```
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setAlpha(75);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.addRect(166, 748, 314, 890, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.rotate(45);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: If you're curious about Path.Direction, why not Google?  First hit - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.Direction.html.  Why are you rotating the canvas before you draw the path?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it says clockwise and counterclockwise,i'm not understand its meaning. simple, i just want to rotate the rectangle i created "path.addRect(166, 748, 314, 890, Path.Direction.CW);". if i remove canvas.rotate(45), it will display a rectangle on screen, now i want to rotate it to 45 degree. already googled it but cannot find any solution

Comment: You've rotated the canvas then you draw the path.  So only whatever is drawn before the path (looks like nothing) is rotated.  Why no draw path then rotate?

Comment: you mean like this?

  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
  paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  paint.setAlpha(75);

  Path path = new Path();
  path.addRect(166, 748, 314, 890, Path.Direction.CW);
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  canvas.rotate(45);
its not working, same, nothing changes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To draw a rotated rectangle you need to rotate the canvas *before* drawing, (then rotate it back to right-side up if you're drawing anything else). `Canvas.rotate()` just alters the canvas's transformation matrix, which transforms shapes drawn *after* the call.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45);
canvas.drawRect(166, 748, 314, 890, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Path.Direction has nothing to do with rotation transforms. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.Direction.html):

> Specifies how closed shapes (e.g. rects, ovals) are oriented when they
>   are added to a path.

Comment: note that `canvas.rotate` by itself will rotate around the origin.  If you want to just rotate the rect about it's center, you will need to call `canvas.translate(rectCenterX, rectCenterY)` and adjust your rect appropriately.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to draw something from `(x,y)` point, you have to rotate the canvas around `(x,y)` point. For doing this you should use

```
canvas.rotate(45,x,y);
```

so,

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45,x,y);
//all drawing from (x,y) point
canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper way should be something like this:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addRect(166, 748, 314, 890, Path.Direction.CW);
canvas.save(); // first save the state of the canvas
canvas.rotate(45); // rotate it
canvas.drawPath(path, paint); // draw on it
canvas.restore(); // restore previous state (rotate it back)
```